# CSS pseudoelement "after"

Tags: css

I'm trying to use two pseudoelements `:after`, but only the first one is working:

```
[data-msgcounter]:after {
    background-color: #FF6969;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    content: attr(data-msgcounter);
}​

[data-notcounter]:after {
    background-color: #FF6969;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FF6969 0%, #ff0000 100%);
    content: attr(data-notcounter);
}​
```

Anyone have tips or a solution?

Comment: could you also post the markup and show the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: let me guess.. are these styles for a single element?

Comment: If so, this is a duplicate of [What happens if multiple classes of the same element define a :before pseudo-element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111751/what-happens-if-multiple-classes-of-the-same-element-define-a-before-pseudo-ele) - the only differences being attribute selectors instead of classes, and :after instead of :before, neither of which are pertinent.