# Css pseudo-element ::before(2); :before and ::before

Tags: css

I'm working with css and I have tried to add an element 'before' to my div like an arrow. Is there any way to achieve it? I tried pseudo :before but there are three of them (::before(2), :before and ::before). They make me so confuse, what are differences in between?

Comment: `::before` is the new implementation of the older `:before` -- it was to distinguish the difference between pseudo-elements (::) and pseudo-classes (:). Having said that, IE 8 only accepts `:before` and not the new syntax, while new browsers accept both, so it's better off using the old syntax if you want better compliance. I have **no** idea what `::before(2)` is, I've never seen it before.

Comment: It looks like `::before(2)` is for multiple `::before` pseudo-elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting however, no major browser supports it yet: http://realworldvalidator.com/css/pseudoelements/::before(2) so don't use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have multiple :before pseudo-elements for the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998593/can-i-have-multiple-before-pseudo-elements-for-the-same-element)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [CSS spec on content](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/) describes all three syntaxes.

- `:before` -- outdated syntax for pseudo elements.  Use if older browser support is needed such as IE8.  IE9 supports the new syntax.  [It also seems like iOS Safari does not support the new syntax](http://caniuse.com/#search=::)
- `::before` -- new pseudo element syntax.  This is equivalent to `::before(1)`
- `::before(n)` -- used to create multiple `before` elements that can be before other `::before`s.  [Details are in the same spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting0).
- As far as I can tell, no browser supports this.

  - http://jsfiddle.net/535Rf/

Comment: question is if they will support the ::before(n) in future?

Comment: @EveryScreamer We're in the future. The answer is no. (The question was posted some six years ago, and since then, all references to it have disappeared from the draft spec//_

Comment: @Jasper shame :(

Comment: well I need it now, I really need it