# Need help for CSS Psuedo elements in Custom Css skin Telerik Controls

Tags: html, css, telerik

So here is poor me,trying to apply custom css to RadTabStrip with following css and html.Although this is telerik control but the problem is just pure css/html.
I am trying to design Menubar as shown in image below.

Please note that i dont want to use RadTemplate,so i can not change DOM here.

Please look at code snippet and images below to get an idea of problem!

```html
<div class="RadTabStrip_Custom">
    <div class="rtsLevel rtsLevel1">
        <ul class="rtsUL">
            <li class="rtsLI FirstChild">
                <span class="rtsLink">
                    <span class="rtsTxt">Delivery Settings</span>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="rtsLI rtsSelected selectedLI rtsClicked">
                <span class="rtsLink">
                    <span class="rtsTxt">Pick a Template</span>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="rtsLI LastChild rtsClicked">
                <span class="rtsLink">
                    <span class="rtsTxt">Almost Done</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used ::after and ::before to get arrow effect but the thing is when it is selected it should only display border not whole arrow with background-color.I am lost over here,even tried ::after(2) and ::before(2) but i came to know from [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485016/css-pseudo-element-before2-before-and-before) that it is not supported in major browser.How can i get this effect?

```
.RadTabStrip_Custom {
    color: #000;
    font: 12px "Segoe UI",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    line-height: 26px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsUL {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 80%;
    border: 0px solid red;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsLI {
    width: 20%;
    overflow: visible !important;
    position: relative;
    left: 4px;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsLI .rtsFirst {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsGhostTab {
    border-color: #0f1d48;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #324d92;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsLI {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: #b7d6e8 !important;
    padding: 9px;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsLink, .RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsLink:hover {
    background-color: #044666;
    background-image: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 9px;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsSelected .rtsLink, .RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsSelected .rtsLink:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: none;
    color: #b8d5e5;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 9px;
    border-top: 1px solid #b8d5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b8d5e5;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsLink::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    border-width: 22px 0 22px 16px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #004466 #004466 #004466 transparent;
    left: -7px;
}

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsLink::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    border-top: 22px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
    border-left: 16px solid #004466;
    right: -5px;
}

.FirstChild .rtsLink {
    border-left: 1px solid #b8d5e5;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.FirstChild .rtsLink::before {
    content: "";
    border-width: 0;
}

.LastChild .rtsLink {
    border-right: 1px solid #b8d5e5;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.LastChild .rtsLink::after {
    content: "" !important;
    border-top: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
}
```

"pick a template" tab is selected in both images,No worries about inverse color scheme.

What i have design till now
[image: What i have design till now]

What i want to design
[image: What i want to design]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that (if I understand what you want to do), you will have to apply the :hover on the `<li>` but not on `<span>`.

Doing so you will be able to use pseudo-elements on both of them doing something like :

```
li:hover:before {
  //do my border-bottom stuff
}
li:hover .rtsLink:before {
  //do my arrow stuff
}
li:hover .rtsLink:after {
  //do my arrow stuff
}
```

Let me know if it's what you wanted of if I'm not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I used ::before and ::after for inner span "rtsTxt" and it worked... :)

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsSelected .rtsLink .rtsTxt::before

.RadTabStrip_Custom .rtsSelected .rtsLink::before