# Duplicate an element 5 times and overlay it only using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm making my first steps learning to code. I have been taken some courses on Internet since some months ago, and now I decided to continue learning from the practice while I build a Wordpress child theme.

The thing is that I want to duplicate an element and overlay it. Specifically I want to overlay two different typographies for one element.

I discover that it's something possible using pseudo-elements:

```css
.button {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.button:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,800" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button" data-title="ABC">ABC</a>
```

Using ::after and ::before I see that I can duplicate two times my element to change the typography. But what if I want to duplicate 5 or more times the same element? And as I see it here ([Can I have multiple :before pseudo-elements for the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998593/can-i-have-multiple-before-pseudo-elements-for-the-same-element)) It's not possible using pseudo-elements.

I'm looking for a solution but I can't find it. I already tried to use two classes for the same element and like this I can write two times ::before and ::after but it doesn't work.

Do you have a suggestion?

Thank you for your help

Comment: use as many `inline` elements like `span` as you wish inside the `a` tag

Comment: @kukkuz - OP does state "only using CSS".  Your suggestion requires HTML.

Comment: Answer : Not possible

Comment: So is there a possibility using html too?