# Add third element to a div containing :after and :before

Tags: html, css

I want a button, and I want it like this:

[image: Icon]

So I begun coding it:

```css
.IconBasic {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
}

.IconBasic:before, .IconBasic:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #000000;
}

.IconBasic:before {
    transform: translate(-210%, -50%);
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.IconBasic:after {
    transform: translate(110%, -50%);
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="IconBasic"></button>
```

For some reasons I don't want to add more html; I would like to to this only with css. Does anyone know it is this possible?

Edit: I know about [Can I have multiple :before pseudo-elements for the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998593/can-i-have-multiple-before-pseudo-elements-for-the-same-element), but this is not this case. I know that you can not add more pseudoelements, but there are other ways, and this question is about this problem.

Comment: [Use `box-shadow` instead](http://one-div.com/pictos/3dots/).

Comment: Good idea, thanks!

Comment: i was about to give you an answer, but it was closed :s

Comment: Yeah, the managers don't read the questions, only its headers… ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: then rephrase the title question , so it reflects at best the real question ;) ... cause a third pseudo leads to the duplicate ;), a single pseudo with box shadow or font-size + letter spacing will do the job by the way ;=

Comment: Yeah, I just edited it!

Comment: an example with a single pseudo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VrWpax

Comment: @NikitaSöze There are no “managers” here. The user who closed your question has the [`css` gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/247/css). Your question still pretty much sounds like _“Is it possible to add a third pseudo-class to an element?”_, even after your edit. You can still share your research and explain that you know about that other question (the duplicate target) and explain why it doesn’t answer your question.

Comment: Thank you Xufox! Ok, then I will change the header and add the reference of the other question