# Nested pseudo-elements

Tags: css, nested, pseudo-element

Why can't we declare nested pseudo-elements like below,

```
.a{...}
.a:before{...}
.a:before:before{...} /* This */
.a.after{...}
.a:after:after{...}   /* And this */
```

Is there any alternate solution to this scenario?

Comment: **Because we can't!** ...ask the CSS Specifications team why not. They tried it ( as i recall) but the browser vendors couldn't get it to work. The alternative... *proper HTML structure*

Comment: Related if not dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998593/can-i-have-multiple-before-pseudo-elements-for-the-same-element

Comment: hahaha!! sorry but it is very funny question.

Comment: @RajnishCoder - Glad that I could make you laugh :)
Now is there any alternate solution(other than the one Paulie mentioned) to this scenario?

Comment: @GibinEalias Yes, Of course you can create nested inline elements inside `a` tag. for example `<span></span>`

Comment: @GibinEalias What **specific** problem are you trying to solve since what you are trying to do is not possible with CSS.

Comment: I have a popup which is in `:after` pseudo-element and I need to style a section of the text.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you are out of luck...but without a specific example to work from it's hard to offer suggestions. Perhaps you should ask **that** quesion instead.