# Can I use ::Before::Before?

Tags: css

I was editing a CSS for a page where you have a profile and can't add content. Reinforcement that cannot add content.

So what's my idea, I'm taking page id and adding in css `::before` before `::before`?

something like that:

**HTML I can't change**

```
  <body>

    <div class="alpha">Main div</div>

  </body>
```

**Atual CSS**

```
.alpha::before {
  position: absolute;
  display block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  content: "First Before";
  background: #09f;
}

.alpha::after {
  position: absolute;
  display block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: -58px;
  height: 100px;
  content: "First After";
  background: #09f;
}
```

**Goal CSS**

```
.alpha::before::before {
  position: absolute;
  display block;
  margin-top: 240px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  content: "Second Before";
  background: #09f;
}
```

**photo of how it is and how I'm trying to change it... As requested.**
[image]
[image]

**And this is the code running**

```css
.alpha::before {
  position: absolute;
  display block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  content: "First Before";
  background: #09f;
}

.alpha::after {
  position: absolute;
  display block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: -58px;
  height: 100px;
  content: "First After";
  background: #09f;
}

.alpha::before::before {
  position: absolute;
  display block;
  margin-top: 240px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  content: "First Before";
  background: #09f;
}
```

```html
<div class="alpha">Main div</div>
```

Can the post be reopened? my doubt was not answered and I still have to choose a correct answer since there was a divergence between answers

Answer (score 2):

That's not allowed, you can only have two pseudo elements on one HTML element, `:before` and `:after`.
For more information [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11999197/11850259).

Comment: I've already used an ``after`` and a ``before``... The problem is this, that I'm running out of id to add these two elements.

Comment: Please add code and scrinshot of what you're trying to accomplish using pseudo elements and explain where you use them.